# WakefulIntentService starts immediately after scheduling

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am attempting to use CommonsWare's WakefulIntentService in a new application, specifically its ability to easily schedule the intent service to run at a later time.

I have a PreferenceActivity that allows the user to pick the schedule that the service is run (daily at 5am for example).  Once the user makes a change to the preference value, I call:

```
AutoDownloadIntentServiceAlarmListener alarmListener = new AutoDownloadIntentServiceAlarmListener();
alarmListener.setForcedHour(5);  // we want to schedule alarm for 5am everyday.

WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(alarmListener, this, true);
```

For some reason, the desired IntentService (that extends WakefulIntentService) immediately starts up and performs its work.

Here is the implementation of of AutoDownloadIntentServiceAlarmListener:

```
public class AutoDownloadIntentServiceAlarmListener implements WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener {

private static final String TAG = "AutoDownloadIntentServiceAlarmListener";
    private int mForcedHour = -1;

    @Override
    public long getMaxAge() {
        return AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2;
    }

    public void setForcedHour(int forcedHour) {
        mForcedHour = forcedHour;
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager alarmManager, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Context context) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String autoDownloadTimePref = MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefs().getString("autoDownloadEpisodesSchedule", "0");

        int hourOfAlarm = Integer.parseInt(autoDownloadTimePref);
            // if this class has been created with a specific hour
            // use it instead of the value obtained from SharedPreferences above.
        if (mForcedHour > -1) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Forced hour has been set for this AlarmListener. " + mForcedHour);
            hourOfAlarm = mForcedHour;
        }
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfAlarm);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Scheduled inexact alarm for %d", hourOfAlarm));
    }

    @Override
    public void sendWakefulWork(Context context) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AutoDownloadIntentService.class);

        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, serviceIntent);
    }

}
```

It is my intention that the service does not startup as soon as it is scheduled, and instead starts up only at 5am the next day. (and continues to repeat on this schedule indefinitely, or until the user elects to disable or change its schedule)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is my intention that the service does not startup as soon as it is scheduled, and instead starts up only at 5am the next day.

Except that's not what your code does, ~80% of the time. Your code says that it should run at 5am *today*, as you are getting the current time and not changing the day. Most of the time, 5am today is in the past, and so `AlarmManager` will immediately do its work.

You need to see if your calculated `Calendar` is older than now, and if so, add a day.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How can I calculate if the "Calendar" is older than now? and add a day?

Comment: @stanleysantoso: Um, `Calendar` has `before()` and `after()` methods for comparison.

Comment: Thanks. now I'm a bit confused. say, now is 10PM. alarm is set for 8PM, which is 22.00. and 8PM is before current hour. that means it will be added by a day? which is 24 Hours? so new alarm will be set for 46.00?? is that how it will work?